# X Axis not showing up R

Tags: r

I am trying to use two different Y axis with the same X Axis and when I set both axes to false the Year wont show up

```
library(lubridate)

x <- dataset$Date
y <- dataset$AvgCostPerKwh
z <- dataset$ActualkWhSold


par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 6) + 0.1)

plot(year(x),y, pch = 16, axes = FALSE, ylim = c(0.030,0.090), xlab = "",  ylab = "",
 type = "b", col="black", main = "Wholesale Power cost")

axis(2, ylim =(range(c(y))), col = "black", las =1)

mtext("$ per KWh", side = 2, line = 2.5)
box()

par(new = TRUE)


plot(year(x),z, pch = 15, xlab = "", ylab = "",ylim=c(5000000,45000000), 
 axes = FALSE, type="b", col="red")

mtext("Kwh's Sold", side=4, col="red", line=4)
axis(4, ylim=(range(c(z))), col = "red", las=1)



mtext("Year", side = 1, col="black",line=2.5)

legend("topleft", legend = c("AvgCostPerKwh", "ActualKwhSold"),
   text.col = c("black", "red"), 
   pch=c(15,15),col=c("black", "red"))
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t95vG.png)

When I set one of the plots to true, I get overlapping values one one side, but the year on the bottom shows up.

```
library(lubridate)

x <- dataset$Date
y <- dataset$AvgCostPerKwh
z <- dataset$ActualkWhSold


par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 6) + 0.1)

plot(year(x),y, pch = 16, axes = TRUE, ylim = c(0.030,0.090), xlab = "", ylab = "",
 type = "b", col="black", main = "Wholesale Power cost")

axis(2, ylim =(range(c(y))), col = "black", las =1)

mtext("$ per KWh", side = 2, line = 2.5)
box()

par(new = TRUE)


plot(year(x),z, pch = 15, xlab = "", ylab = "",ylim=c(5000000,45000000), 
 axes = FALSE, type="b", col="red")

mtext("Kwh's Sold", side=4, col="red", line=4)
axis(4, ylim=(range(c(z))), col = "red", las=1)



mtext("Year", side = 1, col="black",line=2.5)

legend("topleft", legend = c("AvgCostPerKwh", "ActualKwhSold"),
   text.col = c("black", "red"), 
   pch=c(15,15),col=c("black", "red"))
```

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5WcR.png)

I am not sure, I have followed other examples on here about 2 Y axis and I can't get mine to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered my own question for anyone interested, I forgot to add

```
year(as.Date(dataset$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),"%Y")
```

at the top before adding

```
plot(year(x), y, pch=16, axes=FALSE, ylim=c(0.030,1), xlab="", ylab="", 
 type="b",col="black", main="Wholesale Power Cost")
```